# Filtering Access Report based on Access Form field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Form and an Access Report. 
What I would like to do is create a macro so that when a user clicks a button, the Report is automatically filtered to the specific record on the form.

Note: The [Store Name] field is not identical to the [Store Number] field. In the past, I have been manually going into the report and filtering the Report using Text Filters>Contains> my value.

Example: The [Store Name] might be "#001 - Los Angeles", but my [Store Number] is 001, so I am filtering the [Store Name] field with text that CONTAINS 001.

Here's what I got so far:

```
Private Sub Command466_Click()
  Dim myVariable As String
  myVariable = [StoreNumber]
  DoCmd.OpenReport "Report Query", acViewPreview, , [Store Name] Like myVariable

End Sub
```

I'm not great at VBA, so I've been receiving this error:

"Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression".

Comment: Out of curiosity: Have you tried googling for "access open report filter"?

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument of [`OpenReport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openreport-method-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method must be a valid SQL `WHERE` clause without the word `WHERE`.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Command466_Click()
  Dim myVariable As String
  myVariable = [StoreNumber]
  DoCmd.OpenReport "Report Query", acViewPreview, , "[Store Name] Like '*" & myVariable & "*'"

End Sub
```